# Restored VG has shifted volumes

Tags: linux, lvm, data-recovery, ext4, raid

I'm recovering a PV on a mdadm RAID 1 with a single VG containing several LVs.

The underlying devices have several bad sectors (one just a few, the other really much) and a silly typo made it necessary to restore the LVM configuration by grepping through the devices. Luckily I found it and the restored configuration looks like the original one.

The only problem is that the logical volumes have no valid file system. With e2sl I found that one of the superblocks of my target fs is in the wrong logical volume. Sadly I have no idea how to correct or circumvent this issue.

```
root@rescue ~/e2sl # ./ext2-superblock -d /dev/vg0/tmp  | grep 131072000
Found: block 20711426 (cyl 1369, head 192, sector 50), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
root@rescue ~/e2sl # ./ext2-superblock -d /dev/vg0/home | grep 131072000
Found: block 2048 (cyl 0, head 32, sector 32), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 526336 (cyl 34, head 194, sector 34), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 1050624 (cyl 69, head 116, sector 36), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 1574912 (cyl 104, head 38, sector 38), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 2099200 (cyl 138, head 200, sector 40), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 6293504 (cyl 416, head 56, sector 56), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 6817792 (cyl 450, head 218, sector 58), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 12584960 (cyl 832, head 81, sector 17), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 20973568 (cyl 1387, head 33, sector 49), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 32507904 (cyl 2149, head 238, sector 30), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 63440896 (cyl 4195, head 198, sector 22), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
Found: block 89655296 (cyl 5929, head 139, sector 59), 131072000 blocks, 129988776 free blocks, 4096 block size, (null)
^C
```

I'm feeling just an inch away from accessing my filesystem(s) again to recover some non-backed-up data.

LVM Configuration:

```
root@rescue ~ # pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/md1   vg0  lvm2 a--  2.71t 767.52g

root@rescue ~ # vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  vg0    1   5   0 wz--n- 2.71t 767.52g

root@rescue ~ # lvs
  LV        VG   Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  backup    vg0  -wi-a--- 500.00g
  container vg0  -wi-a--- 500.00g
  home      vg0  -wi-a--- 500.00g
  root      vg0  -wi-a--- 500.00g
  tmp       vg0  -wi-a---  10.00g
```

VG Configuration:

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.95(2) (2012-03-06): Sun Oct 13 23:56:33 2013

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *after* executing 'vgs'"

creation_host = "rescue"        # Linux rescue 3.10.12 #29 SMP Mon Sep 23 13:18:39 CEST 2013 x86_64
creation_time = 1381701393      # Sun Oct 13 23:56:33 2013

vg0 {
    id = "7p0Aiw-pBpd-rn6Y-geFb-jyZe-gide-Anc9ag"
    seqno = 19
    format = "lvm2" # informational
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

            pv0 {
                    id = "GBIwI4-AxBa-6faf-aLfB-UZiP-iSS9-FaOrhH"
                    device = "/dev/md1"     # Hint only

                    status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                    flags = []
                    dev_size = 5824875134   # 2.71242 Terabytes
                    pe_start = 384
                    pe_count = 711044       # 2.71242 Terabytes
            }
    }

    logical_volumes {

            root {
                    id = "1e3gvq-IJnX-Aimz-ziiY-zucE-soCO-YU2ayp"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 128000   # 500 Gigabytes

                            type = "striped"
                            stripe_count = 1        # linear

                            stripes = [
                                    "pv0", 0
                            ]
                    }
            }
            tmp {
                    id = "px8JAy-JnkP-Amry-uHtf-lCUB-rfdx-Z8y11y"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 2560     # 10 Gigabytes

                            type = "striped"
                            stripe_count = 1        # linear

                            stripes = [
                                    "pv0", 128000
                            ]
                    }
            }

            home {
                    id = "e0AZbd-22Ss-RLrF-TgvF-CSDN-Nw6w-Gj7dal"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 128000   # 500 Gigabytes

                            type = "striped"
                            stripe_count = 1        # linear

                            stripes = [
                                    "pv0", 130560
                            ]
                    }
            }

            backup {
                    id = "ZXNcbK-gYKj-LJfm-f193-Ozsi-Rm3Y-kZL37c"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_host = "new.bountin.net"
                    creation_time = 1341852222      # 2012-07-09 18:43:42 +0200
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 128000   # 500 Gigabytes

                            type = "striped"
                            stripe_count = 1        # linear

                            stripes = [
                                    "pv0", 258560
                            ]
                    }
            }

         container {
                    id = "X9wheh-3ADB-Fiau-j7SR-pcH9-hXne-K2NVAc"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_host = "new.bountin.net"
                    creation_time = 1341852988      # 2012-07-09 18:56:28 +0200
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 128000   # 500 Gigabytes

                            type = "striped"
                            stripe_count = 1        # linear

                            stripes = [
                                    "pv0", 386560
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What command did you use to restore the LVM configuration?

Comment: I followed the way described at http://rouge.eu.org/blog/linux/recovering-crashed-lvm-setup/

Comment: I managed to mount one of the volumes using a loop device on the raid volume with the correct offset - I will report back if I manage to bring this other idea to work. - Nevertheless, if someone has another solution, please comment :)

Comment: If you have bad offsets, you either used the wrong LVM backup file ; or another possibility, the partitions or the mdadm itself uses different offsets now, which would have caused you to lose your LVM data in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has a similar problem:

I used e2sl [1] to actually find candidates for the filesystems directly from one of the RAID devices and mounted the filesystem using a loop device [2] skipping LVM and the software RAID. I had to fiddle a bit with the offset (The superblock position has an offset of 1KB to the start of the partition!) but in the end I managed to do it.

From there the rescue was easy as pie: Mounting the loopdevice to a mount point and everything was there to be copied.

[1] http://schumann.cx/e2sl/

[2] mount --loop & see losetup

Comment: For RAID1, and *unfragmented* LVM volumes, this is probably the easiest solution. Just find the filesystem offsets and you're good. For other RAID levels or fragmented LVs, you have to find the cause for the shift. `mdadm`'s defaults regarding data offsets and such changed over time, so that's usually the culprit when you re-created your RAID with the wrong settings. Of course LVM itself may have offsets too, but that should be covered by the LVM backup you restored...